# Convert Json table arrays to objects with jq

Tags: text-processing, json, jq

I am trying to convert a json structure that key1: array of values, key2: array of values ,.... to an array of objects. The size of arrays is same and each object is just aggregate of items at position x in each array. 
Need help converting this preferably with generic code with jq.

Input

```
{
  "IdentifierName": [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
  ],
  "Code": [
    5,
    8,
    19
  ]
}
```

Expected Output

```
[
  {
    "IdentifierName": "A",
    "Code": 5
  },
  {
    "IdentifierName": "B",
    "Code": 8
  },
  {
    "IdentifierName": "C",
    "Code": 19
  }
]
```

Edit:
progress so far:

```
jq 'to_entries|map(.key) as $keys| (map(.value)|transpose) as $values |$values|map($keys, .)'
```

The last step is to somehow index with the keys into the values that I am still unable to get right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question:

```
jq 'to_entries|map(.key) as $keys| (map(.value)|transpose) as $values |$values|map([$keys, .] | transpose| map( {(.[0]): .[1]} ) | add)'
```

Explanation: Extract keys ["IdentifierName", "Code"] and values as [ [ "A", 5 ], [ "B", 8 ], [ "C", 19 ] ]
Then to index from keys to values, take json-seq of key-tuple with (each) value tuple and transpose and zip them in pairs.

```
 echo '[[
    "IdentifierName",
    "Code"
  ],
  [
    "C",
    19
  ]
]'|jq '.|transpose| map( {(.[0]): .[1]} ) | add'
```

Combining both gives solution. This will work for any number of elements (0 and 1 are just key and value, not first and second).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ jq '[.IdentifierName, .Code] | transpose | map( { "IdentifierName": .[0], "Code": .[1] } ) ' file.json
[
  {
    "IdentifierName": "A",
    "Code": 5
  },
  {
    "IdentifierName": "B",
    "Code": 8
  },
  {
    "IdentifierName": "C",
    "Code": 19
  }
]
```

I'm extracting the two arrays into an array (of two arrays) that I transpose.  For the given data, this produces `[["A",5],["B",8],["C",19]]`.  I then map each individual element of this array to an object with the wanted keys.

This could possibly be made neater somehow.  For example, it would be *nice* to not have to reconstruct the objects at the end with explicit key names, and it would also be nice if one could generalize this to *n* sub-arrays, not just two.

Comment: This is helpful, am I still trying for a generic answer.